# How to create Cancel button on UISearchbar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

How I create Cancel `button` on `UISearchbar`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is a bit vague, but I will attempt to answer it as best as I can.

If you just want to show the cancel button, it is as simple as:

```
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
```

If you are looking to do some customization work on the cancel button, you'll have to find it in the subviews of the UISearchBar.

```
    for (UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton *)[searchBar.subviews lastObject];
            //Make changes to the cancelButton here

        }
   }
```

Any other questions you should check out the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on UISearchBar.

Comment: is not work I click on cancel button but is not done the search

Comment: If you show me some code that would help.